# How to handle columns like 'country' and 'age groups' while making a prediction model in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I am much new to machine learning and while I was working on this specific data-frame, I found it difficult to handle important columns like age groups and country.

Here is a link to the data-set I am using:

https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016

In the more precise prediction of the data, the columns 'country' and 'age group' are pretty much important. But I am constantly getting the errors like:

```
{ 
  could not convert string to float: '15-24 years' 
}
```

And similar for the country column.

What could I do to make them suitable for the model?

Comment: split age up into two values, say lower bound and upper threshold. Map countries to integers (some kind of ids) which can be used for training the model. The choice of your data layout is strongly connected to the sort of network or model youi want to train, so better check out documentations for different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

These are "categorical" attributes of your machine learning model.  Typically categorical attributes are assigned an integer value so that the ML model can handle them.  This is a major topic in machine learning, so all I can do is suggest you read up on categorical data.  Perhaps [this link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-categorical-data-in-machine-learning-models) or one similar will give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are talking about is categorical. 
Basically the data that you have in your dataset is mostly ordinal(numeric) or categorical.

I would recommend you handle this by converting the categorical variables to dummy codes.
For example assume you have a dataframe like the one below

```
Id, Country
1, US
2, UK
3, Germany
```

Converting this to dummy code will give you

```
Id, US, UK, Germany
1, 1,0,0
2, 0,1,0
3, 0,0,1
```

There are multiple packages which convert categorical data to dummy codes. I think pandas has a function as well.

And then the above dataframe can be used to train your model

Comment: I found the solution for columns 'county' and 'sex'. But using this method for 'age groups' doesn't feel right to me since the age groups in the dataset are random without any pattern and this would create a lot of values which will be difficult to handle. Any help here, please?

Comment: @TanmayJain From the dataset that you have shared it looks categorical and it follows a pattern `5-14 years,15-24 years,25-34 years,35-54 years,55-74 years,75+ years`.                        Let me know if you need more clarification